# How to use soft assertion in CodeceptJS

Tags: javascript, allure, codeceptjs

I would like to use soft assertion in CodeceptJS as like in TestNG. Because currently I am using I.dontSeeInTitle(“Page missing”) and I.dontSee("") Whenever my page encounters issue my execution stopped in the middle, but I need to continue my execution until the end even though it encounters the assertion but it should record the report.

Answer (score 0):

The current CodeceptJS version 2.3.5 does not support soft assertions.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of tryTo plugin. See the original documentation: https://codecept.io/plugins/#tryto

```
const isTitleVisible = await tryTo(() => I.see('Page title'));
// do futher steps
// fail test in any required place by validating the "tryTo" return 
assert.ok(isTitleVisible, 'Page title was not visible');
```